# Real world applications of exponential function; continous case

Tags: education, applications

I am looking for *interesting* applications in everyday life, technology or science of exponential functions of the type:

$$
f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto ab^x
$$

for the case $a > 0$ and $b > 1$.

I am also interested in other examples which are in some way fascinating or funny for this case.

I **don't** want any *discrete* examples or such involving the Euler number $\mathrm{e}$.

Any suggestions for that?

Comment: maybe try the half life decay in radioactivity.

Comment: @mookid Yes but thats for the case $b < 1$, it's a decay. I know there are many interesting (quasi-)continous examples with $b < 1$, but I didn't know any really interesting examples for $b > 1$ which are **not** discrete.

Comment: oh I did not see the condition on $b$.

Comment: We cannot throw out functions of $e$.$\begin{align}f(x) &= ab^x \\ &= e^(ln(ab^x))\\ &= e^(ln(a) + ln(b^x))\\ &= e^(ln(a) +xln(b)\\ &=e^{c +bx}\end{align}$

Comment: Well that's clear. The point is just that I cannot assume that students are familiar with $\mathrm{e}$.

Comment: @Julia how is $e$ (the base of the natural logarithm) any different from $b$? It can be introduced as "just another  real number". You could also write $b$ but know that it is really $e$ (though I think this a potentially troubling approach).

Answer (score 2):

$a>0$ and $b>1$ correspond to exponential growths. Thius kind of formula is used in studies about population, virus, bacteria, ...But you have one case which is very common : make a deposit of $a$ dollars on your bank account and let us suppose that the bank gives you an interest of $r$% per year. After $n$ years, your initial $a$ dollars will become $a \left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^n$ dollars.

Now, if your bank is generous and if you are patient, you will be rich. Suppose that you invest today $100$ dollars, that your generous bank gives you a $5$ % interest (give me its name) and that you are ready to wait for $20$ years, then, in year 2034, you will be able to cash $265$ dollars.

Unfortunately, with bacteria and virus, this goes much faster. For example  if we start with only one bacteria which can double every hour, by the end of one day we will have almost 17 million bacteria.

Another example is the number of cell phones. They increased just as bacteria (slightly slower but very fast).

Comment: Dollars, bacteria and cell phones are all discrete.

Comment: @BradS. Almost everything can be made discrete or continuous, I bet; it just depends how far is the observer from the object. But you are correct ! I just wanted to take simple, practical examples and avoid physics (by the way : particles are discrete, just as atoms or molecules, don't you agree ?). Cheers.

Comment: Yes. of course. It is actually a pretty interesting question. I'm sitting here with my morning coffee trying to think of an example...I'm thinking maybe the mass of a tree or some such similar growth.

Comment: Enjoy your coffee, think about it and come back, please. I think that you initiated a very interesting discussion. Have a nice sunday. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Your compound interest example is excellent. I remember banks (and savings & Loans) in the 1980's advertising "continuous compounding" and "compounded daily".

Comment: @BradS.By the way, dollars and cents are discrete !!

Answer (score 0):

$$ab^x\ \ \  (a>0,\ b>1)$$

That's the law of [exponential growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth).

It has a lot of applications, see e.g. [Wikipedia: Exponential growth - Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth#Examples), [Beispiele](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentielles_Wachstum#Beispiele,_allgemein_und_n%C3%A4her_erl%C3%A4utert).

Exponential growth is the reciprocal of [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay).